# winrt(metro) getthumbnailasync returns icon

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, icons, thumbnails

So using the `GetThumbnailAsync()` call returns icons when there are no thumbnails available.

Does anyone know if there is a way to just get the thumbnail if there is one but never return the icon when there isn't one?

Thanks!

Comment: Any help? I think this might not be possible... :(

Comment: I think this might be closed with "not possible".